# js filter() function

Tags: javascript, функции, filter

```js
function filtterByThanos(items) {
    return items.filter();
}

const posts = [1,2,3,4,5,6];


const filtered = filtterByThanos(posts);
console.log(filtered);
```

При нажатии на которую со страницу пропадало половина результатов поиска.
Вам нужно сделать пойти так же – а именно написать функцию, которая на вход
принимает массив и возвращает новую массив, в котором содержатся только
элементы с нечетными индексами из первого массива.

Comment: И в чём сложность?

Comment: я новичок, пока работаю над этим)

Comment: пробовал разные варианты, но бот не одобряет мой вариант...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function filterByThanos(items) {
    return items.filter((item, index) => index % 2 !== 0);
}

const posts = [1,2,3,4,5,6];


const filtered = filterByThanos(posts);
console.log(filtered);
```

```js
function filterByThanos(items) {
    return items.filter((item, index) => index % 2 !== 0);
}

const posts = [1,2,3,4,5,6];


const filtered = filterByThanos(posts);
console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: можете подсказать, что означает "items" - не понял этот момент... спасибо

Comment: `items` это объекты, которые вы передаете в функцию. В вашем случае это массив с числами. `item` это один объект. То есть метод `filter` берет по одному объекту из массива и потом что-то с ним делает, в данном случае делит на 2 с остатком, проверяет наличие остатка и в зависимости от ответа возвращает либо `true` либо `false`.

Answer (score 1):

Можно покороче, воспользовался ответом о Апполо

```js
const filterByThanos =(а)=>а.filter((_,i) => i%2);


const posts = [1,2,3,4,5,6];


const filtered = filterByThanos(posts);
console.log(filtered);
```